Temp file error when creating index on very large MySQL RDS table
I have a very large (750 million rows) table in MySQL (5.7) RDS using the Aurora (2.11.5) engine.  There is currently no new data being written to the database, and I am trying to create an index on on of its columns before it starts being used.
However, I am consistently receiving this error: "Error Code: 1878. Temporary file write failure."
I have tried upping the tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size parameters, but am still receiving this error.

Would partitioning be useful for this table?

The error occurs when you run out of storage space. I don't know how this would happen on Aurora, which supposedly allocates more storage on demand. Maybe that feature doesn't work for temp space. This is a question for AWS support. It's not a code-related question.
